# from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search

Tags: search, https, web-search

Recently we moved our whole web site from HTTP to HTTPS. 2 days ago I have received email from Google search saying "Page indexing issues detected in submitted URLs" - main reason: "Page with redirect".
So, web server redirects HTTP calls to HTTPS version of each page where HTTPS versions are not indexed yet by Google.

Do we need resubmit every page in web site again but this time as HTTPS or there exists a shortcut solution which can expedite re-indexing of our web site pages? What is a recommended practice here?

We didn't try any fix so far.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this would be better asked at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as StackOverflow is for programming questions.